# Sort or map two arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a section array `['part one','part two']` and an array of item objects `[item1,item2,item3]`.

Each item object has a section attribute ( in this case with the value of 'part one' or'part two') and an order attribute which is an integer.

I want to create an array like

```
[ ['part one',[item1,item3]],['part two',[item3]] ]
```

or

```
[['part one',item1,item3],['part two',item3]]
```

where

```
item1.section == 'part one' and item1.order == 1, 
item3.section == 'part one' and item3.order == 2, 
item2.section == 'part two' and item2.order == 1
```

Comment: You want to group the items by `item.section`, sorting each group by `item.order`?

Comment: @Stefan yes thats correct

Comment: @xlembouras nothing that works

Comment: shouldn't `['part two',[item3]]` be `['part two',[item2]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group by `section`, and order by `order` you can do the following:

```
items.sort_by(&:order).group_by(&:section).to_a
# => [["part one", [item1, item3]], ["part two", [item2]]]
```

[`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) orders all the items according to the `order` attribute, while [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) groups them into a hash of arrays, each key is a different `section`. `to_a` turns the hash into an array.

---

If you want to keep the order of the `section` list, you can use it to define the order instead of `to_a`:

```
grouped = items.sort_by(&:order).group_by(&:section)
# => { "part one" => [item1, item3], "part two" => [item2] }
sorted = sections.zip(sections.map { |s| grouped[s] })
# => [["part one", [item1, item3]], ["part two", [item2]]]
```

Comment: good answer but the section array is needed as it holds the correct order